# HashMap threadsafety when iterating over values

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

Is there any elegant way to make iterating over HashMap.values() threadsafe WITHOUT making a copy of the underlying map?

cheers.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Collections#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) ?

Comment: Important part about `#synchronizedMap()` "It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views". Safer / faster might be using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in the first place

Answer (score 3):

1) The only possibility with HashMap is to completely synchronize all access to the map.

2) Use ConcurrentHashMap which is threadsafe (without being fully synchronized internally)

Answer (score 2):

The `Collections` class in Java contains methods for making various collections synchronized. In your case you should use the [`synchronizedMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) method like this

```
mySyncedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(myMap);
```

It is important to note that this method puts a wrapper around the map but the underlying map is still accessible if you keep the reference to it.

The other option is to use the the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) class as it is mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really agree with R.Moeller's answer. With a `ConcurrentHashMap` you don't get `ConcurrentModificationExceptions` while iterating, but it's still not considered threadsafe (see comments).

I would stick with the copy approach, although I wouldn't copy the HashMap.
If you have a `HashMap<K,V> myMap` iterate over `new ArrayList<V>(myMap.values())`. Makes it easier.

Another approach would be to use a simple counting loop without iterators.

Of course both approaches are not threadsafe so you should include additional checks. Also, concurrently added elements while going through `values()` will not be available. I don't think that there is an API solution to that... You'd have to extend `ConcurrentHashMap`, creating an iterator which takes deletions and additions into account. But I might be wrong with this part and maybe it's even impossible to do.

Comment: You do NOT get ConcurrentModificationException while iterating on a ConcurrentHashMap. The javadoc clearly states "They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException", and I haven't seen them do it either. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: And in the next sentence it says "However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time." So no exception, but still wrong behaviour I'd say.

Comment: but that's the most common use case: the collection may be shared, but the iterator is rarely passed to another thread

Comment: It is talking about a case where a created iterator object is passed to multiple threads and used concurrently, which is a pretty uncommon pattern.

Comment: Indeed. I misunderstood that part.